# use the arcfour cipher with sshfs and google cloud

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I would like to use the arcfour cipher when mounting a drive using sshfs. However, if i specify `sshfs -o Ciphers=arcfour` my virtual machine resets the connection (I am able to sshfs without this option). Any way to make this work? I am doing this so that sshfs performs faster (I also have compression off).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arcfour cipher is no longer supported in modern SSH servers because it is considered insecure. You may want to try `aes128-ctr` or `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`.

Comment: ahh i see; are those faster than whatever the default cipher is?

Comment: You should try it yourself, I've seen different results, it may depend on hardware and library versions.

Comment: great, thx. can't upvote your answer due to rep < 15 unfortunately

Comment: Maybe worth noting, "arcfour" is RC4 by a different (non-trademarked) name.

Comment: According to this link: https://blog.famzah.net/2010/06/11/openssh-ciphers-performance-benchmark/ `aes128-cbc` is faster. But in my tests, without any parameter is faster than specify this.